# trying to create a row on a table after making a POST -django

Tags: python, django

How can I create a new row in table notificacao everytime i make this post? (save is not working i get 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save')

```
def post(self, request):
        cliente1 = Cliente.objects.get(cpf=request.data['cliente1_cpf_transf'])
        cliente2 = Cliente.objects.get(cpf=request.data['cliente2_cpf_transf'])
        notificacao1 = Notificacao.objects.all()

        if cliente1.saldo >= request.data['quantia']:
            cliente1.saldo -= request.data['quantia']
            cliente1.save()

            cliente2.saldo += request.data['quantia']
            cliente2.save()

            notificacao1.cpf_remetente = request.data['cliente1_cpf_transf']
            notificacao1.cpf_destinatario = request.data['cliente2_cpf_transf']
            notificacao1.valor = request.data['quantia']
            notificacao1.save()
```

Comment: ```notificacao1``` is queryset, you apply ```save``` function on instances of model(```Notificacao```)'s instances such as ```cliente1``` and ```cliente2```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QuerySet` is kinda like a list, and you cannot save all objects in list just like that.

You are probably in need to make `notificacao1` as new `Notificacao` object. You need to create it like this:

```
notificacao1 = Notificacao.objects.create(cpf_remetente=cliente1, cpf_destinatario=cliente2, valor=request.data['quantia'])
```

Whole suggested code:

```
   def post(self, request):
        cliente1 = Cliente.objects.get(cpf=request.data['cliente1_cpf_transf'])
        cliente2 = Cliente.objects.get(cpf=request.data['cliente2_cpf_transf'])
        valor = request.data['quantia']
        
        if cliente1.saldo >= valor :
            cliente1.saldo -= valor 
            cliente1.save()

            cliente2.saldo += valor 
            cliente2.save()

            Notificacao.objects.create(cpf_remetente=cliente1, cpf_destinatario=cliente2, valor=valor)
```

Because this is calling all objects of model `Notificacao`:

```
all_objects_of_notificacao = Notificacao.objects.all()
```

Comment: Now i understand! I'll try to use this code, thank you very much!